# How to fix Error 500 using CSOM before login on sharepoint front-end

Tags: csom, sharepoint-2016

I get a "500 Internal Server Error" on execution of "context.executequery" when sharepoint is not used for one day or I restart sharepoint front-end application pool. Just once I log in to the sharepoint front-end (with any user) and everything works as before.

I have just checked that all of server services on Central Administration and that all application pools on IIS are running.

The code I execute is this:

```
...
_context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(__sharepointUserName, __sharepointPass, __sharepointDomain);                ;

Web web = _context.Web;
_context.Load(web.Lists);
_context.ExecuteQuery(); // Here throws an exception
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem warming-up SP with [this script](https://github.com/spjeff/spbestwarmup) (in the page you can find all necessary information on how to install and execute it).
Seems to be a problem generated by IIS that recycles applications pools every night to keep clean memory space. So, When the recycling occurs during mid night (or when you do manual recycling/IISReset), the first user who logged-in to sharepoint "forces" the SP warm-up.

Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/08/sharepoint-2013-warmup-script-powershell.html#ixzz5v4P39RH5